# conservation law for the trajectories

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, physics, chaos-theory

Is it possible to find the conservation equation as the form of  $Q=h(x,y)$, given that

$$\dot{x}=x-xy$$
$$\dot{y}=5xy-5y$$

I am not sure how to start with.

Comment: Differentiate to get $h_x\dot x+h_y\dot y=0$. Combine with $h_{xy}=h_{yx}$ and solve for $h$.

Comment: thanks for answering, but what does hx stand for? @A.S.

Comment: Partial derivative of $h$ w.r.t. $x$

Comment: but we dont know h(x,y), is it possible to do hxy=hyx, cheers @A.S.

Comment: You are solving for $h$ and you have two equations in two functions: $h_x=f$ and $h_y=g$ and their derivatives: $f_y=g_x$.

Comment: the only thing I know about is $h_x\dot{x}+h_y\dot{y}=0$, so $h_x$ can be written in terms of $h_y$, no clue on how to derive $h_x$ and $h_y$ independently. As i know, $\dot{x} = \frac{dx}{dt}$, cheers @A.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Divide" one equations by another and find a separable equation
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{5xy-5y}{x-xy},\,
$$
integrate.

Comment: yeah thats what i did, I finally got the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

1. Construct from the given coupled ODEs
   $$\tag{1} \dot{x}~=~f(x,y)~:=~x(1-y), \qquad \dot{y}~=~g(x,y)~:=~5(x-1)y, $$
   an [inexact differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential) 
   $$\tag{2} \omega~:=~g(x,y)\mathrm{d}x-f(x,y)\mathrm{d}y.$$
2. Find an [integrating factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) $\lambda$ to the inexact differential (2)
   such that
   $$\tag{3}\mathrm{d}(\lambda \omega)~=~0.$$
3. [Poincare Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoincaresLemma.html) then implies that there locally exists a function $h$ such that
   $$\tag{4}\lambda \omega~=~\mathrm{d}h. $$
4. Argue why such $h$ from eq. (4) would be constant/conserved along a trajectory of the systems of coupled ODEs (1).
5. Show that $$\tag{5}\lambda ~=~\frac{1}{xy}, \qquad x~\neq~ 0~\neq~ y,$$ is an integrating factor.
6. Determine from eq. (4) that
   $$\tag{6}h(x,y)~=~5x+y-\ln|x^5y|, \qquad x~\neq~ 0~\neq~ y,$$ 
   is a conserved quantity.
7. We can define a globally defined conserved quantity as
   $$\tag{7} \tilde{h}(x,y)~=~e^{-h(x,y)}~=~x^5ye^{-5x-y}.$$